# Identification request - iris on San Francisco peninsula

Tags: identification

This iris volunteered in our garden on the bank of a stream.  Can anyone identify it?  The flowers are brown above and yellow below.
[image][image][image]

Comment: We really need a photograph please...

Comment: @Bamboo:  I posted three, one of the overall plant and two of the flowers  When I reload the page they show up for me.

Comment: FYI, they do show up for me also.

Comment: It has the form (sort of) but not the color of Purdy's Iris: https://www.fs.fed.us/wildflowers/beauty/iris/Pacific_Coast/iris_purdyi.shtml. The leaves also are not really a match. Perhaps a cultivar?

Comment: I have received a suggestion of Iris foetidissima, which looks reasonable.